# How to do Digital Asset Links Verification on the sites that does not give an access to root folder like Shopify?

Tags: google-play, shopify, progressive-web-apps, digital-assets-links, pwabuilder

I have generated a PWA of my Shopify site. Now, I want to upload it on the Google Play Store, so I used [PWABuilder](https://www.pwabuilder.com/) to create my app package. I have successfully completed all the steps and generated the store package.

Now, As suggested [here](https://github.com/pwa-builder/CloudAPK/blob/master/Next-steps.md#1-deploy-assetlinksjson) to work PWA in the full-screen mode (without Chrome address bar) I have to upload the `assetlinks.json` file on the server at `https://myserveraddress.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json` location.

> 1. Deploy assetlinks.json.
>    Your zip file contains assetlinks.json. This is a digital asset links file that proves ownership of your PWA. Upload this file to your server at https://example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json. (Replace example.com with your PWA's URL.)

> ‍♂️ Heads up:
> Digital asset links are required for your PWA on Android. If you're seeing a browser address bar in your app on Android, or if your app is crashing on launch, it means your assetlinks.json file is missing, inaccessible, or incorrect. See our asset links helper to fix this.

But there is no way on Shopify to upload any file at a specific location. We can upload files but the uploaded files on Shopify store and serve on CDN, there is no way to upload any file on the root.

So, how we can do Digital Asset Link Verification on a site that does not give us access to root like Shopify?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try handling Digital Asset Link verification request through Application Gateway if any exists pointing to a different location since you don't have option to upload any file to root folder of app?
or else, it has to be included with a custom routing to point to a different URL with in your app.